# How to find whether iphone/ipad is upright or laying flat

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

If I call for `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`. It will give me the orientation not position. So can anybody give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIInterfaceOrientation *orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {

    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {

    }
```

Comment: Above code will give me portrait or landscape. But i need whether the device is in  horizontal or vertical position.

Comment: Whether the device is on the table (horizontal position )or in hand (vertical Position).

Comment: That is the angle you are looking for. I don't think there is a way to get that.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm looking for something similar. I looked at the CMGyroData but that's not quite right either because that is the *rate* of rotation, rather than the position of rotation.

Comment: I'm checking out UIDeviceOrientation for this as a simple way to do it without the gyroscope or accelerometer.

Comment: ok but please note that you need iPhone 4 or higher since only these have the gyroscope